# How to null safe check array element in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

In my application I have the following line:

```
<div *ngif="MyService.data[4]['result']['score']">Test content here</div>
```

However, it show me the following error:
`ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'score')`

I did try the use the `!!MyService.data[4]['result']['score']` but still the same error.  I also try the following `MyService?.data[4]['result']['score']` but still no luck.

My question, how can I safely use array like this without flowing the error.

Comment: I recommend setting anything you want to display in the template as a variable in the controller to avoid these. Indexing into some array assuming it's there is not a good practice